# How to know when two async functions have finished?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

```
 func load(completionHandler:(someVar1 : SomeType, someVar2 : SomeType)-> Void){ 
   asyncFunc1() {
   (someVar1) -> Void in
   }
   asyncFunc2() {
   (someVar2) -> Void in
   }
}
```

How would one go about communicating when both functions have completed? Id like to be able to code my load function's completionHandler to execute when BOTH asyncFunc1 and asyncFunc2 are completed to then return both someVar1 and someVar2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a counter to know when both methods finished executing. Having a counter is more scalable, as it allows for virtually any number of async methods:

```
func load(completionHandler:(someVar1 : SomeType, someVar2 : SomeType) -> Void){ 
    var callbacksLeft = 2
    let completionCallback = {
        print("All calls completed, let's do some work")
    }
    func checkCompleted() {
        callbacksLeft -= 1
        if callbacksLeft == 0 {
            completionCallback()
        }
    }

    asyncFunc1() { someVar1 in
        checkCompleted()
    }
    asyncFunc2() { someVar2 in
        checkCompleted()
    }
}
```

Or, if the functions can be called the same way, e.g. both have no params, or have the same parameters list, you can shorten the code by using an array (this also less error-prone as in the first implementation you'd have to update the code in two places if you add a new function - update the `callbacksLeft` value, and add the actual function call):

```
func load(completionHandler:(someVar1 : SomeType, someVar2 : SomeType) -> Void){ 
    let funcsToCall = [asyncFunc1, asyncFunc2]
    var callbacksLeft = funcsToCall.count
    let completionCallback = {
        print("All calls completed, let's do some work")
    }

    for funcToCall in funcsToCall {
        funcToCall {
            callbacksLeft -= 1
            if callbacksLeft == 0 {
                completionCallback()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And even if the functions are not called the same way, you can wrap them in closures:

```
let funcWrapper1 = { (callback: () -> Void)
    return asyncFunc1(argumentsForFuc1, callback)
}
let funcWrapper2 = { (callback: () -> Void)
    return asyncFunc2(argumentsForFunc2, callback)
}
let funcsToCall = [funcWrapper1, funcWrapper2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how efficient this method is, but you could declare two global variables initialized to`nil`, and when each of the methods would finish execution, you would set its respective global variable to `someVar1` or `someVar2` values, and call a third method which will only execute if both those global variables are not `nil`.

```
var flag1: SomeType!
var flag2: SomeType!

func load(completionHandler:(someVar1 : SomeType, someVar2 : SomeType)-> Void){ 
   asyncFunc1() {
   (someVar1) -> Void in
       flag1 = someVar1
       completionMethod()
   }
   asyncFunc2() {
   (someVar2) -> Void in
       flag2 = someVar2
       completionMethod()
   }
}

func completionMethod() {
    if flag1 == nil || flag2 == nil {
        return
    }
    // Completion code here
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea. I was going to use this as a last resort but I figured I was probably just being a bad programmer...

Comment: I'd think the same thing. It doesn't really feel like it's the most efficient way in the world.

Comment: Just implemented it and, it works fantastic. RIP efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you to use global variables at all. Use completion handlers in your first async function to call second async function. Please check my sample code.

```
enum ErrorMessage:ErrorType {
    case asyncFunc1Error
    case asyncFunc2Error


}

func asyncFunc1(completion:(result:SomeType?,error:ErrorType?) ->Void) {
    print("Do Something Func 1")
    var result:SomeType? //fill it
    //do some checks
    if true {
        completion(result: result,error: nil)
    } else {
        completion(result: nil,error: ErrorMessage.asyncFunc1Error)

    }

}
    func asyncFunc2(completion:(result:SomeType?,error:ErrorType?) ->Void) {
        print("Do Something Func 2")
        var result:SomeType? //fill it
        //do some checks
        if true {
            completion(result: result,error: nil)
        } else {
            completion(result: nil,error: ErrorMessage.asyncFunc2Error)

        }

}
 func load(completionHandler:(someVar1 : SomeType?, someVar2 : SomeType?)-> Void){
    asyncFunc1 { (result, error) -> Void in
        if let realResult1 = result {
            //we have result
            print("Result1",realResult1)
            //call second async
            asyncFunc2({ (result, error) -> Void in
                if let realResult2 = result {

                    print("Result2",realResult2)

                    // if we reach here it means async1 and async2 were successful

                    completionHandler(someVar1: realResult1, someVar2: realResult2)
                } else {
                    //async2 failed
                    completionHandler(someVar1: realResult1, someVar2: nil)

                }
            })



        } else {
            //asyncfunc1 failed
            //you can also send some error
            completionHandler(someVar1: nil, someVar2: nil)

        }

    }

}
```